# Is the unit ball $\{f\in L_w^p(\Omega):|f|_{L_w^p(\Omega)}<1\}$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Given $1≤p<\infty$ and a measurable set $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m^n(\Omega)>0$, the weak Lebesgue space $L_w^p(\Omega)$ is the collection of measurable $u:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ such that  $$|u|_{L_w^p(\Omega)}=\sup_{t>0}(t^pm^n(\{x:|u(x)|>t\}))^{1/p}<\infty.$$ 
>   Is the unit ball $\{f\in L_w^p(\Omega):|f|_{L_w^p(\Omega)}<1\}$?

I don't think it holds because $|.|_{L_w^p(\Omega)}$ is only a quasinorm with $$|f+g|_{L_w^p(\Omega)}\leq 2(|f|_{L_w^p(\Omega)}+|g|_{L_w^p(\Omega)})$$ I struggle to come up with a counterexample of $f,g$ so that $|f|,|g|<1$ but $||tf+(1-t)g||\geq 1$ for some $t\in [0,1]$. As the unit ball is convex in $L^p$, to find a counterexample, I would need to use functions which are in $L_w^p$ but not it in $L^p$. I found that $f(x)=x^{-1/p}$ on $\Omega=[0,1]$ has norm $|f|_{L_w^p(\Omega)}=1$ and is not in $L^p$. This is because $|f(x)|>t$ gives $x<t^{-p}$ so $m^n(\{|f|>t\})=t^{-p}$ and then $|f|_{L_w^p}= \sup_{t>0} t(t^{-p})^{1/p}=1$ and $\int_0^1 \frac1x dx=\infty$. Also I believe any constant function except the zero function has norm 1 on $\Omega$ so I set $g(x)=1$. But then when I try to compute $||f+g||_{L_p^w}$ I get a supremum over $\frac{t}{t-1}$ which is unbounded…